# Why String.endsWith and String.startWith are not consistent?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, locale

I have the below test case and only the first assertion passes. Why?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String i1 = "i";
    String i2 = "İ".toLowerCase();

    System.out.println((int)i1.charAt(0)); // 105
    System.out.println((int)i2.charAt(0)); // 105

    assertTrue(i2.startsWith(i1));

    assertTrue(i2.endsWith(i1));
    assertTrue(i1.endsWith(i2));
    assertTrue(i1.startsWith(i2));
}
```

#### Update after replies

What I am trying to is using `startsWith` and `endsWith` in a case insensitive way such that, below expression should return true.

```
"ALİ".toLowerCase().endsWith("i");
```

I guess it is different for [C#](https://ideone.com/2OcHCx) and [Java](https://ideone.com/yS4TMu).

Comment: Can you please change your question so that you're not doing `toLowerCase()`? What is the character `toLowerCase()` outputs?

Comment: Please see my update with `println`s

Comment: Now try to print `i1.length()` and `i2.length()`.

Comment: OK lengths are different :) I updated my question again.

Comment: [`toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) does not take a string as an argument, and it doesn't return a boolean, so it can't evaluate to true.

Comment: See also Java Bug [JDK-8020037 String.toLowerCase incorrectly increases length, if string contains \u0130 char](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8020037)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because lowercase `İ` ("latin capital letter
i with dot above") in English locales turn into the two characters: "latin small letter `i`" and "combining dot above".

This explains why it starts with `i`, but doesnt end with `i` (it ends with a combining diacritic mark instead).

In a Turkish locale, lowercase `İ` simply becomes "latin small letter `i`" in accordance with Turkish linguistics rules, and your code would therefore work.

Here's a test program to help figure out what's going on:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] foo = args[0].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    System.out.print("Lowercase " + args[0] + " has " + foo.length + " chars: ");
    for(int i=0; i<foo.length; i++) System.out.print("0x" + Integer.toString((int)foo[i], 16) + " ");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Here's what we get when we run it on a system configured for English:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 java Test "İ"
Lowercase İ has 2 chars: 0x69 0x307
```

Here's what we get when we run it on a system configured for Turkish:

```
$ LC_ALL=tr_TR.utf8 java Test "İ"
Lowercase İ has 1 chars: 0x69
```

This is even the specific example used by the API docs for [String.toLowerCase(Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)), which is the method you can use to get the lowercase version in a specific locale, rather than the system default locale.

Answer (score 3):

`İ` is Unicode Character ['LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE' (U+0130)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0130/index.htm), and is a Java String with a length of 1.

`"İ".toLowerCase()` returns a Java String with a length of 2:

- Unicode Character ['LATIN SMALL LETTER I' (U+0069)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/69/index.htm) (a normal `i`).
- Unicode Character ['COMBINING DOT ABOVE' (U+0307)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

And that is because there is no such character as a `'LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE'`. It does not exist in Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

After executing the `toLowerCase()` function, the string length is 2 instead of 1; the lower case version of that character is represented by two characters:

```
000> "İ".length()
===> 1
000> "İ".toLowerCase().length()
===> 2
```

The first character in its lowercase representation is a lowercase latin `i`, while the second character is a diacritic:

```
000> "İ".toLowerCase().charAt(0)
===> i
000> "İ".toLowerCase().charAt(1)
===> ̇
```

So the lowercase string *does* "start with" `i`, but it doesn't end with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is failing because you are using wrong the methods...

`String i2 = "İ"` is a turkish capital form of i, and if you dont give a locale for the conversion then the method will fail

using a locale may help :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String i1 = "i";
    String i2 = "İ".toLowerCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));

    System.out.println((int)i1.charAt(0)); // 105
    System.out.println((int)i2.charAt(0)); // 105

    System.out.println(i2.startsWith(i1));
    System.out.println(i2.endsWith(i1));
    System.out.println(i1.endsWith(i2));
    System.out.println(i1.startsWith(i2));
}
```

the output will be

> 105
>
> 105
>
> true
>
> true
>
> true
>
> true

Comment: What if I do not know the locale?